# iOS Xcode: Do I need to keep two copies of all the splash screen and app icon images inside xcode bundle?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am little bit confused about whether I have to keep the splash screen and app icon images both in the root folder of xcode and inside resources folder or I need to put those in one place only. Currently I am storing the images at both the places as shown below.

[image: Xcode bundle screenshot]

As you can see here in the screenshot, there are two copies of all the splash screen and app icon images inside xcode bundle. Because of this I am getting **copyPNGFileLib** error while building the app.

Please advise me which is the correct approach to store splash screen and app icon related images inside xcode bundle.. THANKS in advance... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Xcode 5 you should use the Asset Catalog feature, which removes the need for references to images, including App icons/launch images, in the project. This makes managing images much simpler and makes things more organized in the filesystem too.

The only limitation is images in the catalog are not localizable, AFAIK. So if you actually need diferent images for different locales, you have to keep these outside of the xcassets file.

You can convert your targets to using Asset Catalog by selecting your Project, then for each target in the Info tab you have options to migrate the Launch Images / App Icons to xcassets.
I had issues with the automatic conversion though, so I just added an Asset Catalog to the project via New File and then added my images to it.

Comment: XCAssets catalogs look nice, but is it possible do not have launch image there? When I delete that image set then actool compile it with error ".../Image.xcassets: None of the input catalogs contained a matching launch image set named "LaunchImage".

Comment: You probably have a reference to the LaunchImage set in one of your targets. Of course you can have Launch Images outside of the xcassets catalog, as I said you may even need to keep them separate, i.e. if you need to different launch images for different locales.

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't have an answer for Xcode 4.x, but I strongly suggest you to move to Xcode 5 if possible. The reason is that it comes with a new feature, Asset catalogs which organizes all your start images and app icons easily. It's a bit confusing in the very beginning but when you are used to it, all your assets will be more organized.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Actually would be moving to xcode 5 after one or two month. Before that I would also like to have the fix with xcode 4.6